# SharePoint 2013 Rest API OData Query

Tags: jquery, rest, ajax, odata

I am calling rest uri from jQuery ajax with filter string comparison startswith as below

```
/_api/lists/getbytitle('Stations')/items?$select=Id,City_Code,City_Name_EN&$filter=startswith(City_Name_EN,'M') and Active eq 1&$orderby=City_Name_EN asc
```

Which is working very good. And I am displaying text by programmatically as below

`Mumbai(Mum)` i.e. City_Name_EN (City_Code)

but is there anyway to filter **startwith(City_Name_EN (City_Code),'M')** .

I tried to make calculated field in above format. But rest api does not allow to filter calculated field.

Is there any way to filter like that.

Comment: in my case spaces are separated by _x0020_ so Serial_x0020_Number in ODATA url works and not %20 or space and comma

Comment: Seems like the filter you gave should already cover what you are trying to do. You are already filtering on the City Name starting with "M". Why do you care what the City Code is? It will give you the same thing. As long as it starts with that city, it doesn't matter if you have `City_Name_EN (City_Code)`  (which is invalid, anyway, because you can only filter on one value at a time) or just `City_Name_EN` (as you already had) in your filter.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear exactly what you want to do, but OData $filter has a startswith that you should be able to use here.

```
$filter=startswith(City_Name_EN,'M')
```

See this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx
and do a find for "startswith".

When in doubt, check the OData spec. SharePoint implements it for the most part, though there are exceptions, e.g., batching.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am very well aware of startswith operator but my requirement is I want filter two fields as a One string For example, City,City_code which I display like "new york (ny)" and I want filter that

Comment: Can't you just 'and' or 'or' the two conditions, as in this post from Sahil Malik?
http://blah.winsmarts.com/2011-8-Using_SharePoint_REST_API_$filter_to_specify_multiple_columns.aspx

Comment: I could have done with 'or' or 'and' but I am using it in jQuery ui auto-complete

Comment: I don't think you've explained the problem you're trying to solve well then. Are you trying to filter based on a selected value?

Comment: No I am trying to filter based on selected text not value

Comment: Ok, so the user selects "Mumbai(Mum)" and you want to make a REST call to retrieve items with "Mumbai" OR "Mum"?